# Selecting a document based on a number/position/index

Tags: c#, vb.net, mongodb

How to find fast a single document in mongodb collection? I have 621,160 document. I am looking one document based on a given number in these collection. what I tried so far is to skip first based on this given number and limit to 1.

At early skips, it loads fast. however, when i want to skip 600 000 documents, it took for more than 10 seconds i think to skip a document based on number/position. How to do it faster?

```
Dim Collection = DB.GetCollection(Of BsonDocument)(collection).Find(emptyFilter)
for each number in numbers
    collection.Skip(number).Limit(1).Single.GetValue(fieldName).ToString
next
```

I am at the point where I  am the last 160 pagination. I got enumerable range of integers starting from 1 to 160. These are my numbers. My problem is that the skip is slow.

Comment: read this and it think you will see why this is happening , it talks about deferred execution [C# MSDN Collection.Skip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: a) not sure why C# tag is on here b) I don't know about MongoDb but even NoSql databases aren't going to work very efficiently if you try to look up documents like this - surely they have some sort of indexable property you can put into the `.Find( )` filter?